# UIAlertView performSelectorOnMainThread

Tags: ios, uialertview, performselector

I'm loading data from a server and when the data is received, I change the view.
For that, I use "performSelectorOnMainThread" and the selector is the method that loads the data
and in the end change the view.

My problem is I want to display a UIAlertView while performing this task.

It works when I use "performSelectorInTheBackground", the problem is on the next view, I display an other AlertView when the view appears and there's a concurrency between the two views

When I try : `  [alertDownload show];

```
    UIActivityIndicatorView *indicateur = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

    indicateur.center = CGPointMake(alertDownload.bounds.size.width / 2, alertDownload.bounds.size.height - 50);
    [indicateur startAnimating];
    [alertDownload addSubview:indicateur];







[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(getPositionList) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];`
```

The UIAlertView is displayed but just before the view changes ...

What's the best way to do this ?

Comment: Be aware that this will not work in iOS 7, since you cannot add subview to `UIAlertView` in iOS 7. I would suggest you use something like: [SVProgressHUD](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD)

Comment: Thanks but I need something to work on iOS 7 :/ Plus the problem isn't about the creation of the UIAlertView but the fact the UI is blocked cause of the synchronous requests I do in the main thread

Comment: Well if you want it to work on iOS 7 then you can not use `UIAlertView ` when adding custom view to it.

Comment: then do not make synchronous call use async version

Comment: I have to make synchronous calls because they are successive calls to different webservices, I used async calls at the beginning but it was a pain in the ass to manage it. I just want to display a simple information to the user that's it's loading. I didn't think it was so impossible with synchronous requests performed in a thread